# Bootstrap modal shows all images and not limited to the images in any given Tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

My question is about a bootstrap snippet as you can see here:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/P2gor

I wanted to use this gallery with tab views as you can see below. But my problem is that when click on first tab (Animal) and open image modal, I see the next button until all images in all tabs are shown. And when I click on second tab (Painting) the modal opens app empty and neither previous nor next button works.

First Tab
[image]

Second Tab
[image]

I want to be able to use this snippet with Tabs, so I'm here seek advice what can I do to make it work. When I click on first tab and browse the images in the modal, I want the next button to disappear when the last image on the current Tab is shown, not after all other images are shown.

Because there is no argument (id / class) passing to the JavaScript methods, I can't figure out how to make this work without making lots of duplication in the JavaScript file.

I'm sorry if this question is too generic and not enough specific.